# Kotlin : can you explain member extension functions?

Tags: function, extension-methods, kotlin

My code is as follows:

```
open class Particle

class Electron : Particle()

open class Element(val name: String) {

    open fun Particle.react(name: String): Unit {
        println("$name is reacting with a particle")
    }

    open fun Electron.react(name: String): Unit {
        println("$name is reacting with an electron")
    }

    fun react(particle: Particle): Unit {
        particle.react(name)
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val selenium = Element("Selenium")
    selenium.react(Particle())
    selenium.react(Electron())
}
```

My output is as follows:

Selenium is reacting with a particle

Selenium is reacting with a particle

I don't understand : why the second output should not be "Selenium is reacting with an electron"?

If I added another subclass

```
class NobleGas(name: String) : Element(name) {

    fun react(particle: Electron): Unit {
        particle.react(name)
    }

}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val neon = NobleGas("Selenium")
    neon.react(Particle())
    neon.react(Electron())
}
```

The output is :
Selenium is reacting with a particle
Selenium is reacting with an electron

Why the second output is "Selenium is reacting with an electron"?

Comment: [Declaring Extensions as Members](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#declaring-extensions-as-members)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extension functions compile to static function calls, and therefore which method to call is determined by the compile-time static types instead of the runtime types of the objects.

There isn't dynamic dispatch here like you get when you call a method that's overridden in a subclass and you get that implementation instead of what's in the base class. Basically, there's no overriding extension functions.

To the specific example: at compile time, inside the `react(particle: Particle)` function, the static type of `particle` is just `Particle` at compile time, so it will always call the extension function that's defined on the `Particle` class.

Comment: I just edit the question, I added a subclass, why in the subclass, the extended function call is not determined by compile-time ?

Comment: It is determined at compile-time. The difference is that in your subclass you have `fun react(particle: Electron): Unit` and in your base-class `fun react(particle: Particle)`

Comment: As said by @zsmb13, extension methods are statically dispatched (at compile time) and not dynamically (at run-time). take a look at https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/875393/Static-Dynamic-Dispatch-ReExplained

Comment: Basically, extensions defined in a class are compiled into *member* functions, not static ones. They are still resolved statically in terms of which function to call, but the implementation of that function is resolved at runtime. I think, it is important in context of this question to avoid confusion.